# Повторение javascript кода бесконечно!

Tags: setinterval, ajax, settimeout

Есть код,хочу заставить его повторяться

```
<script    language="JavaScript">                   //НАЧАЛО
function img() {
    now = new Date();
    hour = now.getHours() + 1;
    min = now.getMinutes() + 1;
    sec = now.getSeconds() + 1;
    if ((hour >= 9) && (hour <= 12)) {
        if ((min >= 50) && (min <= 60)) {
            if ((sec >= 1) && (sec <= 60)) document.write("<img    src=../images/b2.gif>");
        else document.write("<img    src=../images/b0.gif>");
    } else document.write("<img    src=../images/b0.gif>");
} else document.write("<img    src=../images/b0.gif>");
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript">img();</script>
```

Comment: Хороший вопрос содержит в себе ответ. Посмотрите на метки, которые вы присвоили вопросу)

И ещё, назовите, пожалуйста, книгу или сайт, который учит использовать `document.write()`. Я буду посылать ему лучи поноса.

Comment: Что же тогда использовать вместо document.write()?

Comment: Я попробовал с помощью innerit и document
.getElementById

function img()
{
now=new Date();
hour=now.getHours()+1;
min=now.getMinutes()+1;
sec=now.getSeconds()+1;
if ((min>=50)&&(min<=60))
{
if ((sec>=1)&&(sec<=60)) document
.getElementById('times_div')
.innerHTML="<img src=../images/b2.gif>";
setTimeout(img,4000);

else document
.getElementById('times_div')
.innerHTML="<img src=../images/b0.gif>";
setTimeout(img,4000);    ........

И вывел:
<div id="times_div" style="padding: 23px; height: 100%;width:100%;">
</div><script type="text/javascript">img();</script> 

Элемент перестал отображаться

Comment: Такой вариант написал

Опробовал вариант с ById:

<script language="JavaScript">                                                //НАЧАЛО
        function wr_hours()
{
time=new Date();
time_sec=time.getSeconds();
time_min=time.getMinutes();
time_hours=time.getHours();
if (time_hours==16 && time_min==50) 
 document.getElementById("<img src=../images/b2.gif>").style.display="block";
else
Это была первая часть

Comment: Вторая часть:

if (time_hours==16 && time_min==47) {
 document.getElementById("<img src=../images/b.gif>").style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("<img src=../images/b2.gif>").style.display="none";
}
else
{
 document.getElementById("<img src=../images/b2.gif>").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("<img src=../images/b.gif>").style.display="none";
}
}
 
wr_hours();
setTimeout("wr_hours();",5000);
                                    </script>                                     <!--КОНЕЦ-->

Но не обновляется картинка и все до истечения времени своего действия и все тут!

Comment: не обновляется и все!